# Prevent changes to constructor signature in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, you can do:

```
class Foo {
  constructor(a: string) {
    
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  constructor(b: number) {
    super("hi");
  }
}
```

Notice that `Bar` changes the constructor of `Foo`. However, what if I depend on whatever subclass of Foo to have a certain constructor signature? How can I force TypeScript to not allow subclasses to change the signature?

```
class Bar extends Foo {
  // Throw an error that the constructor signature cannot be changed
  constructor(b: number) {
    super("hi");
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't help you with preventing a certain signature (don't think it's even possible or should be) but may I ask *why* do you need to prevent it? What is your original problem? (just checking if that's not an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) )

Comment: You can't directly ensure a class has a specific constructor, you can enforce the constructor signatures in several other ways (for static functions you can type annotate `this`, in general when you assign a constructor to a signature you will get errors) but  I would need the wider context of your use case

Comment: I would like to have instance methods on the class that can create a new instance of the class. This is totally doable, but you need to know the signature of the constructor function. The native Array does this, so I didn’t consider it an antipattern or anything.

Comment: @Splox [there is no real requirement for classes extending the native array to preserve the constructor parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBBATss9oFMAeAXTAdgCYwpoYDeAUNLdMAPYES7ICuwuDyAFC8gC5o-AJYEA5gEpo1OnOFsADpl78AdCELjcAC0k06AXyrGqjZrmhhUARmgBeaAUwB3OElToeAIh2YQIAzekgDc0AD04cBgAWAARprQLiK6wqxi4mZMLFaoAEwOTq7uZF4ALHmhEeEEDJbRsQmYSSk6TmwAtnEqQA)

Comment: [Try mapping over the array](http://shorturl.at/dopwN) and you'll notice that there is an implicit requirement that the array constructor not change in order for the map function to not throw an error.